# Are Jews allowed to give gentiles gifts to avoid chillul hashem

Tags: halacha, gentiles, yoreh-deah, gifts, chilul-kidush-hashem

The general [Halacha](https://www.sefaria.org/Avodah_Zarah.20a.4) from the Talmud in Masechet Avodah Zarah is that Jews are not supposed to give gentiles gifts randomly due to the prohibition of Lo Techanem. However I am curious if it is permissible for a Jew to give a gentile a gift If they  ask for it or expect it, simply to avoid a chillul hashem or perform a kiddush hashem?

Comment: Please can you explain what possibilities for chillul/kiddush Hashem exist in this situation.

Comment: I don't know why you need to invoke kiddush Hashem. If they expect it, it's not חינם (free gift) and would not violate לא תחנם.

Comment: Are you talking about situations like a baby shower, wedding gifts, retirement gifts, birthday gifts? Times where a lack of societal courtesy can be offensive?

Comment: If you have a relationship with him it is permitted regardless. See Taz YD 151:8 https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.151.11?lang=bi&p2=Turei_Zahav_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.151.8&lang2=bi

Comment: Basically because "what goes around comes around."